# not able to set custom context root set properly in spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, contextroot

My spring project is working properly on tomcat on context root `'/'` at `localhost:8080` but I am trying to change it to `localhost:8080/myroot`, its giving error.

I made following changes after searching on google. 
Added `application.properties` in `src/main/resources`

```
server.contextPath=/myroot
server.port=8080
```

But this is not working. I just added this file and not changed anything else. Don't know if it is to be linked somehow with spring.

**File web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Getting following error while starting tomcat

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
 53  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open Servlet    Context resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
```

`dispatcher-servlet.xml` is searched on `/WEB-INF/` instead of `/WEB-INF/spring`

Please point where am I doing wrong.